# Odoo - Error en campo selection no permite iniciar al servidor

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

añadi un modelo nuevo al modulo d eodoo que estoy ocupando pero a la hora de actualizar el cambio me manda un error de servidor y no actualiza la pagina

Adjunto codigo:

````
```  class CustomSaleOrder(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'sale.order'

  zone = fields.Selection(['N', 'Norte', ('C', 'Centro'), ('S', 'Sur')], string='Zona 
 comercial')```
````

eso lo añado y recargo el servidor y en la termibnal me manda un error y en el navegador manda el error 500[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que tendria que hacer para corregir el error  poder visualizar el servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los campos tipo `selection` deben de llevar siempre tuplas. Te hace falta parentesis en el primer par:

```
class CustomSaleOrder(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'sale.order'

  zone = fields.Selection([('N', 'Norte'), ('C', 'Centro'), ('S', 'Sur')], string='Zona 
 comercial')
```

Comment: corregi como vienen en la respuesta pero manda el mismo error de que no puede inicializar

Comment: Sorry, me falto un parentesis, y corregi luego.

Comment: listo ya quedo gracias